# Using R to create a while loop with a 1 trial sample that continually adds each result to a given starting number

Tags: r, while-loop, estimation

In general terms my program needs to run under these conditions:

A gambler has an initial capital of say $90 `x0<-90`

He plays a game so that the net result is 1 or -1

```
x <- x0 + sample(c(-1,1), 1, replace=T, prob=c(1-p,p))
```

where `p=0.4`

He continues to play until he either goes bankrupt or gets up $10

This is where I am running into trouble,
I can't seem to continually run the sample and keep a running total that will keep looping until x equals 100 or 0, whichever comes first. (I intend to use p=0.4)

```
p<-0.4
x0<-90
t<-100




while((x !=100) & (x != 0))

    {
    x<- x0 + sample(c(-1,1), 1, replace=T, prob=c(1-p,p))

    gamblers.capital<-c(x0,x)


    }
```

basically I'm running into the problem of there only ever being 1 bet played.
the capital will only go up or down by 1.

Comment: Where does `t <- 100` come in?  What is it for?

Comment: You may be waiting a long while.  Check how many 100s and 0s are in `replicate(1e5, x0 + sample(c(-1,1), 1, replace=T, prob=c(1-p,p)))` when `p = 0.4` and `x0 = 90`. I get absolutely none.

Comment: Perhaps, you could take a large sample at the beggining and find afterwards the first (if any) 0 or 100 that occured? E.g. `x1 = cumsum(c(90, sample(c(-1,1), 1e6, replace=T, prob=c(1-p,p)))); match(c(0, 100), x1)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define `gamblers.capital` before the loop.
Secondly, try with the `repeat` loop (use `if` and `break`) - this will imitate a `repeat..until` or `do..while` loop from other languages.

Comment: Note that `repeat` can be dangerous, getting you trapped sometimes.

Comment: Indeed, so `x` should also be defined before the loop then.

Comment: I think the OP needs to adjust a few things. Check how many 100s and 0s are in `replicate(1e5, x0 + sample(c(-1,1), 1, replace=T, prob=c(1-p,p)))` When p = 0.4 and x0 = 90.  I get a big ol' zero.